# Run tests on sources and then on their minified version

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-closure-compiler, karma-runner

I have JS project: source code + tests. For now tests are run on original sources, everything works great.

But then sources are minified and I want to run all my tests on their minified version as well. Notice, all function names are renamed because of minification. Is it resolvable task? Ideally would be don't make much changes in tests / sources.

My configuration for now is: TeamCity, karma.js + mocha, closure compiler (advanced optimization).

Comment: ps. Another answer I got on karma project page is about using grunt:
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

our approach is as follows. We use the testing suite that comes with closure, we write our tests as per normal and then we use goog.exportSymbol to get the tests working with advanced compilation via "reflection" 
example:

```
product.path.SomethingRegressionTest.prototype.placeInvalidSession = function() {
...
}
goog.exportSymbol('test_placeInvalidSession', function() {
  core.inject(product.path.SomethingRegressionTest).placeInvalidSession();
});
```

We use injection here, and in the teardown we destroy all injected instances, but there are a few approaches you could use.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, I use the modules option to compile the tests simultaneously with the source. It seems to work well. Just make sure your tests are written in a fashion compatible with advanced optimizations.

Here's the jQuery compilation options for the tests: https://github.com/ChadKillingsworth/jquery/blob/closure-compiler-1.9/build/closure-compiler/closure-compiler.flags

Comment: As I understand, if I compile tests together the sources, result will be not the same if I compile just sources - or I'm wrong? Because idea was to test code that will go for production with no further changes.

Anyway, thanks for idea of module options, maybe it will be useful in some cases.